# Select 1 day / week / month from sql server timedate

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, datetime

I have data saved in a sql server database which i am using to draw a graph with in asp.net (c#) one field is an INT and the other is a datetime
At the moment the graph is only drawing for all the data in the table i was wondering if there is any way to add into the sql string a statement that says for only today or this week or this month.

this is my sql string at the moment:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [Time], [Temp] FROM [test2] ORDER BY [Time]"<br>
```

the format that the datetime is in is "2011-03-29 00:46:06.377"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a more efficient way, but my first thought is something like the following:

```
SELECT [Time], [Temp] 
FROM [test2] 
WHERE 
    month([Time]) = month(getdate()) AND 
    datediff(day, [Time], getdate() <= 7 AND
    day([Time])  = day(getdate())
```

And then add parameters to each line for which version you want to use, so you only need the one query.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Month, Day Function of SQL

```
SELECT Month([Time]) as Month,Day([Time]) as Day, [Temp] FROM [test2] ORDER BY [Time]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a number of [`date functions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) such as [`month`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) to return the month part of the specified date.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use any functions on the field from your table. It will be faster to retrieve the data if you don't.

Query for today. First figure out what today is without the time part of `getdate()`

```
declare @Today datetime = dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, getdate()), 0)

select [Time], Temp
from test2
where [Time] >= @Today and
      [Time] < @Today + 1
```

Query for current week. First figure out the first day of the week.

```
declare @FirstDayOfWeek datetime = dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, getdate()), 0)- datepart(dw, getdate())
select [Time], Temp
from test2
where [Time] >= @FirstDayOfWeek and
      [Time] < @FirstDayOfWeek + 7
```

Query for current month

```
declare @FirstDayOfMonth datetime = dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, getdate()), 0)      

select [Time], Temp
from test2
where [Time] >= @FirstDayOfMonth and
      [Time] < dateadd(m, 1, @FirstDayOfMonth)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT [Time], [Temp]
FROM [test2]
WHERE datediff(day/week/month/year, [Time], getdate()) == 0
```